# How can I write a test for an IF statement that uses a String and the sum of an Array in a method with JUNIT

Tags: java, arrays, junit, mockito, tdd

I need to test the BasketBallGame class, ive written multiple tests who work and now I want to test the final IF statement in the method:  public BasketResult play(String category) {}

I have written test for the other two IF statements and used Mockito to mock the ShotAttempt method.

```
@ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({ "0, 1,0", "1,1,1", "0, 0,1" })
    public void MockShotAttempt(int firstValue, int secondValue, int derdeWaarde) {
        Mockito.when(inHoop.ShotAttempt(3)).thenReturn(new int[] {firstValue,secondValue,derdeWaarde});         
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @NullAndEmptySource
    @ValueSource(strings = {"        ", "TodDDleR", "LoWWeR","#!|@" })
    public void Invalid_EmptyCategory(String category) {
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            BasketBallGame.Play(category);
        });
        
    }
```

Now i'm not really sure how I can use the sum of the array value, and the string category in order to test the last IF statement and return a BasketResult.

```java
public class BasketResult {

    private final boolean won;
    private final int amountInHoop;

    BasketResultaat(boolean won, int amountInHoop) {
        this.won = won;
        this.amountInHoop = amountInHoop;
    }

    public boolean isWon() {
        return won;
    }

    public int getAmountInHoop() {
        return amountInHoop;
    }

}

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class InHoop {

    private final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public int[] shotAttempt(int amountAttempts) {
        int[] score = new int[amountAttempts];
        for (int index = 0; index < amountAttempts; index++) {
            score[index] = random.nextInt(2); // 1 = in hoop, 0 = not in hoop
        }
        return score;
    }

}
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BasketBallGame {
    private InHoop inHoop;
    private final int AMOUNT_TRIES = 3;
    private final String TODDLER = "toddler";
    private final String LOWER = "lower";

    public BasketBallGame() {
        this(new InHoop());
    }

    public BasketBallGame(InHoop inHoop) {
        this.inHoop = inHoop;
    }

    public double Calculate(int x, double y) {
        if (x <= 0 || y < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be stricly positive and y must be positive");
        return (AMOUNT_TRIES * 10) - x - y;
    }

    public BasketResult play(String category) {
        if (category == null || category.isBlank()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("category must be filled in");
        }

        if (!categorie.equalsIgnoreCase(TODDLER) && !categorie.equalsIgnoreCase(LOWER)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("INVALID category");
        }
        int[] result = inHoop.shotAttempt(AMOUNT_TRIES);

        int amountInHoop = Arrays.stream(result).sum();
        // IF toddler And 1x in hoop ==> WIN 
        // IF LOWER AND 2X IN HOOP ==> WIN
        if ((category.equals(TODDLER) && amountInHoop >= 1)
                || (categorie.equals(LOWER) && amountInHoop >= 2)) {
            return new BasketResult(true, amountInHoop);
        }

        // did not win 
        return new BasketResult(false, amountInHoop);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is specifically your problem? You control amountInHoop via mocking shotAttempt and category via method argument. Thus, you control every variable in the if condition. Check if the result of the play method meets your expectations and you are done.

Comment: I guess i lack experience in order to know how and what to do. I've managed to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`.
In addition, the statement `initMocks` is necessary.

```java
@InjectMocks
BasketBallGame basketBallGame;

@Mock
private InHoop inHoop;

@BeforeEach
void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
        "toddler, '0,0,0', false",
        "toddler, '1,0,0', true",
        "toddler, '1,1,0', true",
        "lower,   '1,0,0', false",
        "lower,   '1,1,0', true",
        "lower,   '1,1,1', true",
})
public void TestLastIfStatement(String category, String scoreList, Boolean winExp) {
    int[] scoreArr = Arrays.stream(scoreList.split(",")).map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    int sumExp = Arrays.stream(scoreArr).sum();

    when(inHoop.shotAttempt(anyInt())).thenReturn(scoreArr);

    BasketResult result = basketBallGame.play(category);

    assertEquals(winExp, result.isWon());
    assertEquals(sumExp, result.getAmountInHoop());
}
```